# Datatype for submit to database

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-7

I'm sending the contents of text boxes and checkboxes to my database via a WCF service.

So far, I have

- fNameTxtBox.Text, - string
- (DateTime) BirthDate.Value, - System.DateTime
- toggle1.IsChecked, - bool

But what happens if the datatype is int?

Unfortunately the autocomplete does not help me as such, and of course it doesn't accept `.Text` as an ending.

Anybody able to lend a hand and let me know what this would be?

**EDIT:**

Here is my complete statement that I am trying to complete. I am looking for the ending for ownerTextBox which for which the method required it to be an int, when the source is a text box on a WP7 app:

```
    private void addAccountBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    _ServiceClient.AddDriverAsync(fnameTxtBox.Text, snameTxtBox.Text, (DateTime)BirthDate.Value, phonemobNumBox.Text, toggle1.IsChecked, toggle2.IsChecked, toggle3.IsChecked, toggle4.IsChecked, toggle5.IsChecked, toggle6.IsChecked, toggle7.IsChecked, toggle8.IsChecked, toggle9.IsChecked, toggle10.IsChecked, toggle11.IsChecked, toggle12.IsChecked, toggle13.IsChecked, toggle14.IsChecked, toggle15.IsChecked, ownerTextBox.????);
    }
```

ie replace the ???? with the correct ending, or reformat that part as such so that it works.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) And what's your actual question?

Comment: I think you have to use System.Data.SqlTypes Namespace to specify types

Comment: What kind of GUI is it? ASP.NET Web Forms? ASP.NET MVC? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? Please tag appropriately.

Comment: its for a Windows Phone 7 App

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to perform validation on the client to ensure that an invalid value never gets sent to your service. You can do this by checking if the value is a integer, and display a message if its not. Only send the data to your service if it meets the validation criteria.

```
public void OnButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    int value;

    bool isValid = int.TryParse(textBox.Text, out value);

    if (isValid) {
        // send to WCF
    }
    else {
        // display a message
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to parse the value using the int class, e.g.

```
int.Parse(myTextBox.Text)
```

Note that `int.Parse` will throw an exception if the value cannot be represented as an integer, so you may want to perform appropriate validation or exception handling. Look into the [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) family of methods.

You may find it useful to read up on [Casting, Type Conversion, and Parsing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx).

Using the source-code you posted, you would change it to:

```
private void addAccountBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _ServiceClient.AddDriverAsync(
        fnameTxtBox.Text, <snip_lots_of_arguments>, 
        toggle15.IsChecked, 
        int.Parse(ownerTextBox.Text)); //I've only changed the very last bit here
}
```

Comment: hmmm, after adding that, all of my checkBox.IsChecked throw an Argument: cannot convert from 'bool?' to 'bool'.
Didnt have that error before I added that and the checkboxes worked

Comment: Please see my edit - you should only be using `int.Parse` on the specific argument that's an `int`. Note that it sounds like this is an unrelated issue where you have a nullable boolean. Try using `<argument>.Value` on this one.